# why is my css overlapping my content?

Tags: html, css

You can see my webpage here

```
http://209.140.27.232/~ashleyo/portfolio.html
```

I can't seem to figure out whats wrong with my CSS.  It appears that an invisible container is overlapping my content so I can't click on the images with the exception of the bottom ones that seem to be outside the container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remove** `#content` `id` `z-index -1` and

**Now add** `z-index` `0` on your `#content` `id`

**As like this**

```
#content{
z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you :)

Actually here`s neither a need of this "z-index" for CONTENT`s DIV and neither "height" for CONTAINER`s DIV as there`s no need of z-index and height can be grow automatically.

Simply Remove these properties.

```
#content{
    z-index:0;
}
#container{
    height: 500px;
}
```

and if you want you can limit your div`s max hieght with this CSS Property

```
#container{
    max-height: 500px;
}
```